# Date & Time column display strange value in disp form

Tags: sharepoint-designer, date-time

I have created a date & time type of column in my custom list, I have selected date only as display format. I can just fill date in this field on new item form but when i see this field in display item form, i see some extra charaters with the date selected, I just want to display date on display form as well. Please help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What kind of extra characters do you see? Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: "2012-06-01T05:00:00Z" I get this value when i select 1/June/2012. I only get this value on the display form that I've customized, not on the display form created by SharePoint.

Comment: That is the ISO format and can be changed. What method did you use to add this to the display form? IE what code are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use something like:

```
<xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDate(@ArticleStartDate, 1033, 3)"/>
```

Change `1033` to you LocalID and the second number is a format specifier. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa505323.aspx#officesharepointddwrt_formatdate) for possible values.

Make sure you have the `ddwrt` namespace reference `xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime"` in the top of your xsl.

See also: [this SO-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602103/sharepoint-xsl-ddwrt-formatdatetime-issue) and [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joshuag/archive/2009/03/25/custom-date-formats-in-sharepoint-xsl.aspx)

Comment: i used this,worked well <xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDate(@ArticleStartDate, 1033, 1)"/>